# Macro not running in Read only

Tags: excel, vba

So I have created an excel file (File 1) with a macro. The purpose of this excel file is to export the Excel input directly to our Access Database.

When our engineers open the file, the file opens as a read-only file since it's protected by a password. 
Once the file is open, our engineers have to give some input on some subjects. Once everything is filled in, they simply press on a button to save it to our Access Database.

While backtesting the code (NOT in read-only), it seemed to be working perfectly. My input was saved to the database. Once the file is open in Read-only mode, it exports the last saved data from that excel file thus completely ignoring the new input.

Example:
NOT READ ONLY MODE
Once an engineer opens the file, they see an empty tab since they'll have to retrieve their data from our access database. Engineer fills in their input, presses save, data gets exported to our database.
READ ONLY MODE
Once an engineer opens the file, they see an empty tab since they'll have to retrieve their data from our access database. Engineer fills in their input, presses save, the data from the last saved excel file(thus empty) gets exported to the database

If I save the file with input from person A in it, the input from Person A gets exported while the New input from Person B gets ignored.

What am I doing wrong?
This is the code i use to export from excel to access:

```
dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
dbWS = Application.ActiveSheet.Name

ssql = "INSERT INTO AssistAccruals (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19)"
ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & "[" & ActiveSheet.Name & "$A8:S" & Last_row & "]"
cnDB.Execute ssql
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is: You send an SQL query to your database and this SQL query tells the database to query your Excel file (`SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & "[" & ActiveSheet.Name`). Now the database of course can only access the saved file on the disk but not the un-saved file in your memory.

Your approach cannot work without saving the Excel file. Since it is read only you cannot save it.

This is the problematic part:

```
ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & "[" & ActiveSheet.Name & "$A8:S" & Last_row & "]"
```

Change it in a way that you generate a SQL without querying your Excel file. Provide the list of values directly to send it to your database like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

without using `SELECT`.

Of course you must write a code to generate that string `VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);` from your data source `"$A8:S" & Last_row &`

Comment: But it does work once i open the file in non read only mode without saving it.

If i open the file, retrieve the data from person A, give some random test input and press the "save data" button, it works perfectly even without saving that file.

Comment: @JustinSane I cannot test it, but that sounds very unlogic to me, try what I suggested this approach should work.

Comment: It does sound very unlogic indeed but for some reason it works.

In non read only, it detects the input from the Activesheet //  
In read only mode, it doesn't detect the input from the Activesheet.

Comment: If you do the following: Open the file (non readonly), enter new data eg `AAAA`, press submit to DB button and then **exit Excel without saving**! If you now open your file, is the new data `AAAA` in that file or some of the old data?

Comment: The file gets send to multiple engineers. So when they open the file, its completely empty besides a "retrieve Data button". Once they've retrieved their data, they fill in their input like "1111". When eingineer A opens the file (read-only), retrieves their data, gives the corresponding input and exports it to the database nothing will be exported since the initial (last saved) document is empty. If i for example save the document with the data from engineer A, and Engineer B opens the file(RO), retrieves his data with corresponding input and exports the data from engineer A gets exported.

Comment: @JustinSane I got that part, but I wanted to test if you open it in **non**-read-only mode if the file gets somehow saved without you noticing. Please read my last comment again and test exactly what I wrote. After this test your data in the Excel file is either `nothing` if the file was empty before or `AAAA` the data you entered last. Please test it.

Comment: When you share the workbook with your engineers, does each engineer get a distinct copy of the workbook file, or are they opening the same workbook file as readonly?

Comment: It doesn't save the data. I did open the non read only empty file, retrieved data for Person A and gave a test input. When pressing the export button, it works perectly. 
I then closed the file **without saving** and reopened it. What i got was an exmpty file.
@LanchPad Every engineer has to open the same file ( in read only)

Comment: @JustinSane Thanks for testing. Well, obviously your DB somehow manages to address the correct non-saved Excel data (I have no idea how that works, and it is completely unlogic to me). But if every engineer opens the same file in read only. Then **obviously** your DB cannot know which of the read-only files to address. • The approach I described should work in that case. Give it a try.